# MIMIC-III Citation

Tags: mimic-iii

Is there a new citation for MIMIC-III? If so, what is that citation?

If not, should we continue to use the citation for MIMIC-II?

```
@article{MIMICII, 
  Author = {Saeed, Mohammed and Villarroel, Mauricio and Reisner, Andrew T. and Clifford, Gari and Lehman, Li-Wei and Moody, George and Heldt, Thomas and Kyaw, Tin H. and Moody, Benjamin and Mark, Roger G.}, 
  Title = {Multiparameter Intelligent Monitoring in Intensive Care II (MIMIC-II): A public-access intensive care unit database}, 
  Journal = {Critical Care Medicine}, 
  Volume = {39}, 
  Number = {}, 
  Pages = {952-960}, 
  Month = {May}, 
  Year = {2011},
  Howpublished = {\url{http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3124312/}},
  Note = {}
}
```

Comment: I am not aware of a new citation of MIMIC-III, however, new papers have been submitted to journals using data from MIMIC-III. People interested to write a descriptive analysis of MIMIC-III, feel free to contact me, I have tried to analyze the database to the bone.

Answer (score 5):

The official citation for the MIMIC-III database is:

> MIMIC-III, a freely accessible critical care database. Johnson AEW, Pollard TJ, Shen L, Lehman L, Feng M, Ghassemi M, Moody B, Szolovits P, Celi LA, and Mark RG. Scientific Data (2016). DOI: 10.1038/sdata.2016.35. Available at: http://www.nature.com/articles/sdata201635

The following URL includes further details on how to acknowledge the MIMIC-III project: http://mimic.physionet.org/about/acknowledgments/